# Ajax callback change "checked" radio button

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I have a radio button group like this:

```
$options = array('2' => t('Active (2)'), '1' => t('Upcoming (1)'), '0' => t('Finished (0)'));
$form['active'] = array(
'#type' => 'radios',
'#title' => t('Update state:'),
'#default_value' => $default_entry->active,
'#options' => $options,
);
```

which works fine. However, based on a drop-down list of entries, it calls an ajax function which should update the selection:

```
foreach (array('name', 'test') as $item) {
$form[$item]['#value'] = $entry->$item;
}
foreach (array('active') as $item) {
???
}
```

Now, the "name" and "test" work as expected as they are text fields.... but the active radio button stays the same as it was (i.e. based on the '#default_value').

I have tried

```
$form[$item]['#value'] = $entry->$item;
$form[$item]['#default_value'] = $entry->$item;
```

but neither change which radio button is selected. Is there something I'm missing based on updating the "checked" attribute for that radio group?

Any help and/or points in the right direction much appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing it can't be done. I've seen a couple of other similar issues, but nothing with a viable solution, most notably here:
http://drupal.org/node/1446510

It may be a solution, but I can't get my head around it if anyone could explain a little more, it'd help greatly!

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/276978/how-to-set-default-value-for-radio-button-on-ajax-callback/290917#290917

Answer (score 1):

You would need to show more code (the form definition), I would recommend you to try:

`unset($form['input'][$item]);`

Right prior to calling:

`$form[$item]['#default_value'] = $entry->$item;`

Relative links: https://www.drupal.org/node/1082818#comment-5335080