# Can't update radio button fields after ajax callback

Tags: 8, ajax

I'm having troubles with a FORM in Drupal 8, the idea is:

Chose a radio value from radio-estaciones to recharge radio-contaminantes, but, after the callback, the result I see is empty, but in replace command I use, I see it correcly

This is the code of buildForm

```
public function buildForm(array $form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state){

    $arrRadioContaminantes = array();
    $arrRadioContaminantes["0"] = t("ALL");

    //My function to access DB
    $result = \Drupal\map_data\Controller\Contaminante::list();
    foreach ($result as $it){
        $arrRadioContaminantes[$it["id_contaminante"]] = t($it["description"]);
    }

    $form['radio_contaminantes'] = array(
        '#type' => 'radios',
        '#options' => $arrRadioContaminantes,
        '#ajax' => [
            'callback' => '::seleccionContaminantes',
            'disable-refocus' => true,
            'event' => 'change',
            'wrapper' => 'radios-estaciones',
            'method' => 'replace'
        ]
    );

    $form['radio_estaciones'] = array(
        '#type' => 'radios',
        '#id' => 'radios-estaciones',
        '#options' => ['-1'=>t("SELECT CONTAMINANTE FIRST")]
    );

    $form['actions']['#type'] = 'actions';
    $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
        '#button_type' => 'primary',
    );

    $form_state->setCached(false);
    $form_state->setRebuild(true);

    return $form;
}
```

This is callback function:

```
public function seleccionContaminantes(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
    if($form_state->getValue("radio_contaminantes") != 0){
        $form['radio_estaciones']["0"] = t("All");
    }

    //My Database function
    $resultado = \Drupal\montar_mapa\Controller\Estacion::list($form_state->getValue("radio_contaminantes"));
    foreach ($resultado as $it){
        $form['radio_estaciones'][$it["id"]] = t($it["name"]);
    }

    $ajaxResp = new AjaxResponse();
    $ajaxResp->addCommand(new \Drupal\Core\Ajax\ReplaceCommand('radios-estaciones', \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($form['radio_estaciones'])));

    return $ajaxResp;
}
```

I try returning $form['radio_estaciones'] with same results, and try DataCommand pasing new values, same result... I need help

Comment: Just `return $form['radio_estaciones'];`

Comment: I tried too, the response I have is empty, I only see twigs annotations, nothing else in both cases.

data: <!-- THEME DEBUG --> <!-- THEME HOOK: 'radios' --> <!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/modules/system/templates/radios.html.twig' --> <div id="radios-estaciones"></div> <!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/modules/system/templates/radios.html.twig' -->

I don't know if twig hook is doing something

Comment: If you do, `return 'hello world';` does it work?

Comment: No @NoSssweat in fact, if I use debuger, renderedContent() don't reflect changes either.

Thats the answer I see:

data: <!-- THEME DEBUG --> <!-- THEME HOOK: 'radios' --> <!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/modules/system/templates/radios.html.twig' --> <div id="radios-estaciones"></div> <!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/modules/system/templates/radios.html.twig' -->

Comment: If you switch to the default "Bartik" theme, does the same issue occur? Also try turning off twig debug.

Comment: @NoSssweat

Using "hello world" as return:

ResponseText: TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\AjaxRenderer::renderResponse() must be of the type array, string given

In any case, I try returning a string in html code directly with HtmlResponse, looks ok but, Drupal sends an error after submit, indicating the integrity of data is currupted. I don't reach validate method.

Comment: How I change the theme programmatically?
With no debug, same result, empty <div></div>

Comment: Go to `/admin/appearance` and change it to bartik, this is just for testing purposes. Also comment out your `$ajaxResp` lines.

Comment: Same result @NoSssweat :(

Comment: @NoSssweat returning the array $form['radio_estaciones'] and change the type to "select", not radios work.

Looks like an issue

Answer (score 0):

After change type to 'select' works fine.

Drupal have this bug active

https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2758631

Same situation with checkboxes